# Push notifications for Google Hangouts unreliable on WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, notifications, google-hangouts, push-notifications

I just got a Moto E and am attempting to use Hangouts as both my chat client and my SMS client. This works well except for the fact that it is unreliable about receiving push notifications. The notifications for Twitter, Zoho, Slack generally work fine.

I am running Android 5.0.2. I have not rooted the phone though it is unlocked.

I made sure I had every possible setting I could find turned on.

- In Settings -> Sound & Notification -> App notifications -> Hangouts I have its notifications set to priority.
- I have Messages turned on as an allowed interruption in Settings -> Sound & Notification -> Interruptions.
- In Settings -> Apps -> Hangouts I have "Show Notifications" checked.
- In Hangouts -> Settings -> SMS I have SMS enabled. I also have Auto retrive MMS checked, though not Roaming auto-retrieve because that seemed unnecessary.
- In my account settings in Hangouts, I have hangout notifications turned on.
- In Settings -> Account -> Google Account -> Sync I have everything checked except "Google Play Movies & TV" though *I do not see one specifically for Hangouts* (could that be a problem?). Also, *when I do a "Sync Now", that does not seem to sync Hangouts*.

Most recently, I installed Push Notification Fixer (PNF No-Root) and set the WiFi heartbeat to 1 minute. After a reboot I did receive one notification but I am not yet confident that it is working consistently.

My WiFi during work hours is coming through Connectify on my laptop. Sometimes my phone randomly disconnects by I reconnect it as soon as I see it.

I have seen people trying everything under the sun for this but before I just start randomly trying something I would like to have some reasonable confidence that it may be effective. Anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I had to change my router settings to enable IPv6 in order to get push notifications to work again. Some networks without IPv6 have been unreliable.

Comment: I've found even without IPv6, replacing the router is a factor for this. My home network wouldn't receive any push notifications to my Android devices. I eventually traced it to the fact that my router couldn't handle torrent traffic AND Google's push services at the same time. I replaced the router, which definitely supported IPv6, and boom, I was set.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like GCM Push Notifications don't work with IPv6. I disabled IPv6 entirely in my router and now everything is fine. Though IPv6 was enabled for the past two years and I didn't have any kind of issue. Let's hope a Play Services update fixes it.

here is where i got the answer : Push Notifications not working over WiFi on Google Devices

On rooted devices, you can install this app to fix the problem :  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.lennartschoch.disableipv6

Answer (score 0):

I've had a Galaxy Note 3 for some time. Used to work great, but I haven't gotten a push notification from Hangouts since the Lollipop update. I removed my account, added it again, and checked all my settings. No luck.

Looks like it may be a known issue with the Lollipop update, only on wi-fi. Here's what I found elsewhere on the web: http://www.reddit.com/r/LGG3/comments/32l4xj/verizon_is_aware_of_the_wifi_notification_bug_in/

Try to see if you still get notifications when using mobile data.